# List Comprehensions and Conditions?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to see if I can make this code better using list comprehensions.
Lets say that I have the following lists:

```
a_list = [
        'HELLO',
        'FOO',
        'FO1BAR',
        'ROOBAR',
        'SHOEBAR'
        ]

regex_list =   [lambda x: re.search(r'FOO', x, re.IGNORECASE),
                lambda x: re.search(r'RO', x, re.IGNORECASE)]
```

I basically want to add all the elements that do not have any matches in the `regex_list` into another list.

E.g. ==>

```
newlist = []
for each in a_list:
    for regex in regex_list:
        if(regex(each) == None):
            newlist.append(each)
```

How can I do this using list comprehensions? Is it even possible?

Comment: -1: lambdas.  Just use the regex itself, don't waste time wrapping a perfectly good regex in a function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, I think this should do it

```
newlist = [s for s in a_list if not any(r(s) for r in regex_list)]
```

*EDIT*: on closer inspection, I notice that your example code actually adds to the new list each string in `a_list` that doesn't match *all* the regexes - and what's more, it adds each string once for each regex that it doesn't match. My list comprehension does what I think you meant, which is add only one copy of each string that doesn't match *any* of the regexes.

Comment: Not the same behaviour as the code he gave since "each" will never be appended more than once as in the example. 
However, I believe this is what he actually wanted to achieve.

Comment: One more question, if i were to lets say replace a_list with a function that returns a list. Will it only be called once? Or will it be called at every iteration?

e.g.

def returnalist(): 
return ['klsdfj', 'kldffjsdkl', 'hello', 'somethinghats']

and did:
newlist = [s for s in returnalist() if not any(r(s) for r in regex_list)]

Would returnalist be called constantly?

Comment: It should only be called once, in this case. Although you could always try it and see ;-)

Comment: David, thank You for showing me potential of any. I didn't used it before.

Answer (score 0):

I'd work your code down to this:

```
a_list = [
          'HELLO',
          'FOO',
          'FO1BAR',
          'ROOBAR',
          'SHOEBAR'
          ]
regex_func = lambda x: not re.search(r'(FOO|RO)', x, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Then you have two options:

1. Filter

   `newlist = filter(regex_func, a_list)`
2. List comprehensions

   `newlist = [x for x in a_list if regex_func(x)]`