# Make a list from some of the properties of other list

Tags: python, list

I have one list containing other lists, and want to make a new list from only the n'th item in the other lists.

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],['a','b','b'],[100,200,300]]

new_list = make_new_list(mylist, index=2)

new_list = [2,'b',200]
```

I know how to design a function which grabs all the second elements, but I also know there always exists some pythonic list comprehension which does this much more smoothly. What is the list comprehension?

Comment: In Python, write what you think, it'll probably be correct :)

Comment: In the 90% of programming languages indices start at `0`, not `1` hence you should have written `make_new_list(mylist, index=1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's pretty easy:

```
new_list = [x[1] for x in my_list]
```

Note that in python, the indexing starts with 0, so the second element is at index 1.

Comment: I feel like we've had this answer a thousand times before, how do we make this more searchable?

Comment: @phant0m: maybe by adding links to some of the most rated list comprehension answers ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/826430/1258806), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2656070/1258806)) and to the relevant [PEP 202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the version using a list comprehension as suggested by mgilson, you could also use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(1), my_list)
[2, 'b', 200]
```

Some timing comparison:

```
>>> lis = [[1,2,3],['a','b','b'],[100,200,300]]*10**5

>>> %timeit [x[1] for x in lis]
10 loops, best of 3: 38.6 ms per loop

>>> %timeit map(itemgetter(1),lis)
10 loops, best of 3: 43.8 ms per loop

>>> %timeit map(lambda x: x[1], lis)
10 loops, best of 3: 82.9 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with list comprehensions or you can use python's map function:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],['a','b','b'],[100,200,300]]
newlist = map(lambda x: x[1], my_list)
```

if you want a function that does it:

```
my_func = lambda li, index: map(lambda x: x[index], li)
newlist = my_func(my_list, 1)
```